# add a css to DatePicker GWT Widget

Tags: gwt

I am trying to add a custom background for datapicker, but it's not working for saturday/sunday dates.

You see I am able to see the 5 days of the week, but same code is not working for S and S columns. Can you tell me, how can I change the css of those selected columns, as I am doing in other case?

My current code is:

```
datePicker.addStyleToDates("customeDatePicker", date);
```

Follow this link to see, what I have done so far and what need to be done:
http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6052/6342954519_defcf4d962_m.jpg

customDatePicker

```
public class CustomeDatePicker extends DatePicker {

    public CustomeDatePicker() {

        this.setStylePrimaryName("nakar");
    }

    @Override
    public void addStyleToDates(String styleName, Date date) {
        super.removeStyleFromDates("gwt-DatePicker", date);
        super.removeStyleDependentName("gwt-DatePicker");
        super.removeStyleName("gwt-DatePicker");
        super.removeStyleName("datePickerDayIsWeekend");
        super.addStyleToDates("customeDatePicker", date);
        this.getElement().setClassName("customeDatePicker");
        this.getElement().getStyle().clearBackgroundImage();
        this.getElement().getStyle().clearColor();

    }

    @Override
    public void addStyleToDates(String styleName, Date date, Date... moreDates) {
        super.addStyleToDates(styleName, date, moreDates);

    }

    @Override
    public void addStyleToDates(String styleName, Iterable<Date> dates) {
        super.addStyleToDates(styleName, dates);
    }

}

entrtypoint class



  public class Gwtproj implements EntryPoint {
        /**
         * The message displayed to the user when the server cannot be reached or
         * returns an error.
         */
        private static final String SERVER_ERROR = "An error occurred while "
                + "attempting to contact the server. Please check your network "
                + "connection and try again.";

        /**
         * Create a remote service proxy to talk to the server-side Greeting service.
         */
        private final GreetingServiceAsync greetingService = GWT
                .create(GreetingService.class);

        /**
         * This is the entry point method.
         */
        public void onModuleLoad() {

            final CustomeDatePicker datePicker = new CustomeDatePicker();
            VerticalPanel mainPanel = new VerticalPanel();


             // Set the value in the text box when the user selects a date
            datePicker.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler() {
              public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
                final Date date = (Date) event.getValue();
                // temp code
                datePicker.addStyleToDates("customeDatePicker", date);
                datePicker.getElement().getStyle().clearBackgroundColor();
                datePicker.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("red");
                datePicker.addShowRangeHandlerAndFire(new ShowRangeHandler<Date>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onShowRange(ShowRangeEvent<Date> event) {
                        // hun tak
                        datePicker.removeStyleFromDates(datePicker.getStyleName(), date);


                        datePicker.addStyleToDates("customeDatePicker", date);
                        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

                        datePicker.addStyleToDates("customeDatePicker", date    );
                          datePicker.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("red");


                        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

                        datePicker.addStyleToDates("customeDatePicker", date);
                          datePicker.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("red");

                        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

                        datePicker.addStyleToDates("customeDatePicker", date);
                          datePicker.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("red");

                        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

                        datePicker.addStyleToDates("customeDatePicker", date);
                          datePicker.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("red");

                        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

                        datePicker.addStyleToDates("customeDatePicker", date);
                          datePicker.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("red");

                        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

                        datePicker.addStyleToDates("customeDatePicker", date);
                          datePicker.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("red");
                      /*Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();*/
                /*      cal.setTime(date);
                        cal.add(Calendar.DATE,1);

                        datePicker.addStyleToDates("customeDatePicker",cal.getTime() );*/


                    }
                });


              }

            // ithay calender rakh

            });


            mainPanel.add(datePicker);

            RootPanel.get().add(mainPanel);


        }
    }
```

css class, I have added it in default project css

```
   .customeDatePicker {
      color: red;
      background: cyan;
      border-color: blue;
      padding:2px;
      color: black; 
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are calling `addStyleToDates` for your weekend dates? You need to provide your whole snippet of code. Also provide the CSS style you are adding to the dates. Too hard to see what's wrong.

Comment: Ok, that's better. But still cannot see the problem. Where are you calling addStyleToDates?

Comment: i have done it using below line for each date datePicker.removeStyleFromDates("datePickerDayIsWeekend", date);

Comment: because i don't get the answers of my questions mostly and i able to find the solution myself

Answer (score 0):

I've been hit by the same issue. After searching through and through the only solution I've found to get rid of the default weekend style is to call:

```
datePicker.removeStyleFromDates("datePickerDayIsWeekend",date);
```

right after the addStyleToDates() call/s.

Ok maybe it's not he only solution (you can always make your own implementation of DatePicker), but it's the quickest at least :)

EDIT: If you change months the dreaded 'datePickerDayIsWeekend' style gets back!

You have to implement addShowRangeHandler() to readd/drop the styles again.